# Dealing with multiple program arguments, but only one is allowed in C

Tags: c, console, arguments, flags, getopt

I have a problem figuring out how to reasonably consider which of the available arguments was given in a situation where one can be used, but there is also an optional argument after which one of the mandatory ones can be given. It is specifically about getopt in C. Example: I have a program with the argument -a -b -c and an optional -d. Only one of the first three may be used. Normally I would do something like that:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, OPTSTR)) != EOF)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'd':
        optional_flag = 1;
        break;

    case 'a':
        if (!mandatory_flag)
            mandatory_flag = 1;
        else
            usage_prompt(argv[0]);
        break;

    case 'b':
        if (!mandatory_flag)
            mandatory_flag = 1;
        else
            usage_prompt(argv[0]);
        break;

    case 'c':
        if (!mandatory_flag)
            mandatory_flag = 1;
        else
            usage_prompt(argv[0]);
        break;
```

The problem now is that I'm just checking to see if an optional argument was given and that if many mandatory arguments were not given. I could use a separate flag for each option, but it would be tiresome for many parameters. Is there any better solution to keep the logic but also know which parameter was given? I am thinking about another switch where I will be able to run appropriate functions.

Comment: You could set `mandatory_flag = opt;`, or you could define a `mandatory_opt` variable, and set `mandatory_flag = 1;` `mandatory_opt = opt;`. Does the ordering of the optional argument and the mandatory argument matter?

Comment: You could also replace `mandatory_flag` with a counter incremented each time one of the mandatory arguments is encountered and check it is exactly 1 at the end.

Comment: As for the ordering, the optional argument must be the first. The rest doesn't matter. The opt flag seems fine. I came up with an idea yo check if optional parameter is present in argv array and then I can check if argc == 2 or 3, depends on optional_flag. Due to that I can just run functions in opt switch.

Comment: The nice thing about `getopt` is that *it doesn't care* what order the options are in.

Comment: Re: "*I could use a separate flag for each option, but it would be tiresome for many parameters.*" That's kind of how options work.

Comment: Hmm maybe flags are the way then. I have only four parameters so I can make something like flag_a, flag_b etc. and then make another switch. Or instead of flags make a mask with bits corresponding to options.